# C++: Class pointed to by unique_ptr holding a reference to owner, is this bad?

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, circular-dependency

Is this a bad pattern, or could this result in a cycle that's actually harmful?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo;

class Bar {
    Foo& m_foo;

    public:
    Bar (Foo& _foo): m_foo(_foo) {};
};

class Foo {
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
    bool finished;
    
    void doStuffWithBar();
    
    public:
    Foo(): m_bar(std::make_unique<Bar>(*this)), finished(false) {}
    bool const& isFinished() { return finished; }
    void finish() { finished = true; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    while (!foo.isFinished()) {
         do {
             std::cout << '\n' << "Press a key to exit...";
         } while (std::cin.get() != '\n');
         foo.finish();
    }
    std::cout << '\n' << "Exiting now..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For context, during normal functioning, `Foo` would only be destroyed when quitting the app.

Comment: This post might be useful for you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/306518

Comment: All of your data is publicly accessible, so it's certainly _possible_ that someone could change something in a way that feels harmful to you.  `std::swap( foo1.m_bar, foo2.m_bar );`, for example.

Comment: No immediate problem. It doesn't cause Foo to double-delete itself, or prevent it from being deleted, or anything like that. As Drew pointed out, it doesn't stop you from accidentally mixing up the wrong Bar with the wrong Foo

Comment: *Is this bad?*  **No.**  There are some caveats (as Artyer linked, and Drew mentioned).  I would not use a `Foo& m_foo;`, instead I'd use a `Foo* m_foo;`.  I'd make the member variables private, so the code can ensure its invariants.  I'd add in a debug-build paranoia check to ensure that Foo checks that it's m_bar has a Bar that has a m_foo that points back to that self-same Foo.  Likewise, a paranoia check in Bar.  Consider what ought to happen for a *copy* or a *move* assignment (or if they should be `=delete` away).

Comment: @DrewDormann That was just for the example. They're not actually structs with no private members.

Comment: @Eljay I guess those are valid points re: making sure there's not a mismatch between instances but at least in theory that should never happen because in the real code, Foo is instantiated just once at the main loop level.

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein you may [edit] this question if you feel that the code you've shown us isn't really the code you are asking us about.

Comment: @DrewDormann *shrugs* if you insist; I've updated it to not be THAT naive.

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein I certainly don't _insist_ on you doing anything.  I'm just advising that people are going to assume that you are asking about the code you are showing them.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Bar` constructor is `public` so nothing prevents to use it with some irrelevant `Foo`. Where your idea to create Child within Parent on Parent reference only. If constructor of `Bar` is `private` `Foo` should be `friend` of `Bar`.
2. Since `std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_bar` is private to `Foo` how will you access it? What is the use for reference to Parent in Child that accessible from Parent only? If `m_bar` is `public` someone accidently can break this happy family.
3. Any change in `Bar` force change in `Foo` and vice versa.

What to you want to achieve in your specific case?

Comment: This is all a very simplified mock of the actual scenario.

What I want to achieve? In the real app (a game), `Foo` is a sort of glue class that manages communication between different subsystems. `Bar` is a wrapper for a simple REST server. 

Answering 2: Once it has been built, we only really care about starting/stopping it, and that is done by `Foo` via a couple public methods.

To answer 1: You're right but that would be an evident error and we're a small team, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Chiefly, I wanted to know I wasn't unwittingly doing badwrong memory stuff by using a ref.

Comment: In your case Bar will never outlive Foo so no problem with reference itself (assumed all aware of evident error in answer 1).